# Why is the thread execution order in Debugging and Release modes different?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, release

I am running the C# code below in Visual Studio 2010, Windows XP SP3.

In "Start without debugging" (by Ctrl+F5 or from menu), the output:

- Hello from main
  Hello from worker

"Start with debugging" (by F5 or from menu) shows the opposite order:

- Hello from worker
  Hello from main

Checked many times. It is reproducible and repeatable.
Why?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace _5NamingThreads
{
  class ThreadNaming
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "main";
      Thread worker = new Thread(Go);
      worker.Name = "worker";
      worker.Start();
      Go();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Go()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello from " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**:
Next day, after relaunching computer I always observe the order which is quite reproducible in all modes, Release and Debug:

- Hello from main
  Hello from worker

Follow-up question:
[While debugging, is it possible to ensure the output without stepping into each line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037105/while-debugging-is-it-possible-to-ensure-the-output-without-stepping-into-each)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In debug mode, the thread startup process requires initializing debug contexts in the new thread. This has to be completed before the function returns because the original thread might operate on the new thread. The net result is this slows the original thread enough to let the new thread run first.

Of course, this is not something you should *ever* rely on. It could change in the next version of the operating system, library, debugger, CPU, ...

Comment: what do you mean by "before the function returns?". IMHO, you just can't rely on thread scheduling, that's all.

Comment: As soon as the function that creates the thread returns in the original thread, that thread can perform operations that interact with the created thread. So the debugger must halt the original thread until it has finished setting up the debugger context for the new thread. (And, of course, you cannot rely on thread scheduling unless you specifically force it with mechanisms guaranteed to control it. See my last paragraph.)

Comment: nice, thanks for the explanation about that. How a debugger actually works has always seemed like black magic to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is because spinning up new async threads is non-deterministic.  In other words, developers cannot rely on threads to execute in the same order.  See [race conditions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)