# While debugging, how can I ensure the output without stepping into each line of code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, synchronization

In the following console application, if I place a breakpoint on the last line Go();  and execute till breakpoint (in debug mode) by pressing F5, the results are not quite different on each run.
Console can be blank (does not output anything):

[image: Console is blank]

or it can output just part of the results on another run:

[image: Partial results output]

or, on very rare occasions, the results are "complete" ("actualized"):

[image: the results are "complete" ("actualized")]

If I debug by F10  (Step Over) or F11 (Step into), the results of executing are output into console window immediately.

[image: Stepping through code outputs the results immediately]

Why are such differences?
Suppose I am debugging an application using 3d party libraries to source codes of which which I do not have aссess.
Is it possible to ensure the output from them without stepping into their code?

The code of console application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace _5_2
{
  class ThreadNaming
 {
    static void Main()
    {
      Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "main";
      Thread worker = new Thread(Go);
      Thread worker2 = new Thread(Go);
      worker.Name = "1111";
      worker.Start();
      //string just4breakPoint = "aaa";
      worker2.Name = "2222";
      worker2.Start();
      Go();
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Go()
    {
      Console.WriteLine
        ("Hello from " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Why are such differences?" - It's because step debugging introduces synchronisation of threads, and possibly changes the order in which things happen.

The fact you are flagging this as a problem may indicate that you require synchronisation in your code.

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote, the problem is that I am dealing with 3d party libraries to source codes of which I do not have access (and cannot meddle with them without breaking licensing terms). I hope for The question in the title to be addressed/answered

Comment: I've answered the question: if multiple threads are involved, you can't guarantee output ordering unless you have explicit eynchronisation. Regardless of third party or your own code.

Comment: The question was not about ordering but about having complete output of executed before a breakpoint code. In any order

Answer (score 0):

It became clear to me only [after discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15037124/2031316) that in order to have complete output up to a breakpoint by F5 it is necessary to synchronize output thereafter by executing step debugging by F10 or F11 once. In most cases, this means inserting dummy line of executable code after the line with breakpoint (before or after the line of interest) in order to introduce the ability to synchronize output by means of dummy "stepping" once.